# LDAP - SSH script across multiple VM's

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tmux

So I'm ssh'ing into a router that has several VM's. It is setup using LDAP so that each VM has the same files, settings, etc. However they have different cores allocated, different libraries and packages installed. Instead of logging into each VM individually and running the command, I want to automate it by putting the script in .bashrc.

So what I have so far:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lhome/username
# .so files are in ~/ to avoid permission denied problems

output=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^cpu cores" | uniq | tail -c 2)

current=server_name

if [[ `hostname-s` != $current ]]; then
 ssh $current
fi

/path/to/program --hostname $(echo $(hostname -s)) --threads $((output*2))
```

Each VM, upon logging in, will execute this script, so I have to check if the current VM has the hostname to avoid an SSH loop. The idea is to run the program, then exit back out to the origin to resume the script. The problem is of course that the process will die upon logging out.

It's been suggested to me to use TMUX on an array of the hostnames, but I would have no idea on how to approach this.

Comment: can't you run the "remote" command in the background from the sub-shell that is spawned remotely by ssh? i.e. `ssh remHost "remCmd &"`. Or am I missing the point? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install `clusterSSH`, set up a list of hostnames, and execute things from the terminal windows opened. You may use `screen/tmux/nohup` to allow processes started to keep running, even after logout.

Yet, if you still want to play around with scripting, you may install `tmux`, and use:

```
while read host; do
    scp "script_to_run_remotely" ${host}:~/
    ssh ${host} tmux new-session -d '~/script_to_run_remotely'\; detach
done < hostlist
```

**Note**: `hostlist` should be a list of hostnames, one per line.